# Is it possible to add clickable link to chart

Tags: apache-superset

At the moment I am making a comparison couple of BI tools. And now I've started my acquaintance with Superset.
I've already created some simple charts and dashes. But I need to test some "advanced" features.

For example: I have chart with the following table

| Name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| John | 5 |
| Andrew | 4 |

and I need to add to digits it the Count field link to other chart with details.

I want to click the 5 in front of John and get to other chart

| Name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| John | Record 1 |
| John | Record 2 |
| John | Record 3 |
| John | Record 4 |
| John | Record 5 |

How can I to integrate link into some filed?

Comment: I'm not able to help you with your question, but I think what you are trying to achieve is called "Drill down" capability in BI tools. Maybe googling that term will help you to find if that's possible with superset.

Comment: Stop adding bad tags.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you can add links to Table chart. The cell value should be something like below:

```
'<a href="external_url" target="_blank">text_to_show</a>'
```

Detailed tutorial by Preset:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhQfnADr-4I&ab_channel=PresetUser%27sCorner